# Search without case sensitivity across different MySQL columns

Tags: php, mysql

On my website I have a search integrated. I tried full text search, but it is not case insensitive as I would like. Artist and song are in different columns in MySQL.

The code is:

```
public function search($query, $page_num = 1, $cid=null) {
    if (empty($page_num)) $page_num = 1;
    $items = $this->db->get_results('SELECT added, store.id, categories.id AS category_id, categories.name AS category_name, artist, song, file, size, youtube_url, downloads, hits
        FROM store LEFT JOIN categories ON (store.cid = categories.id)

        WHERE MATCH(artist, song, added) AGAINST ("+' . $this->db->escape($query) . '" IN BOOLEAN MODE)

        '. ($cid!==null ? ' AND store.cid = "'.intval($cid).'"' : '') .'
        ORDER BY added DESC
        LIMIT ' . ($page_num - 1) * SONGS_ON_PAGE . ', ' . SONGS_ON_PAGE, ARRAY_A);
```

Comment: To search for textual phrases, you may find the "full text search" feature in MySQL worth looking at. It will return results, and they can be ordered by relevance to (i.e. how well they match a row). What version of MySQL are you running?

Comment: Regarding the material you posted in an answer box, would you now edit that into the question? Thanks!

Comment: my MySQL Version is 4.0.10.6

Comment: is it possible to change my code to WHERE CONCAT...?

Comment: No, that's not the way to do it. Try [full text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/fulltext-search.html). Your MySQL version is extremely old - you are advised to update to 5.5 at least.

Comment: why not? whats wrong with my code? the problem is, i have managed server and i dont think that the version is the oldest, maybe ive look wrong for the version number. how my code would look like with full text search? for example SELECT * FROM store WHERE MATCH... IN BOOLEAN MODE...?

Comment: @pstephan1187 explained what is wrong with `CONCAT` - it is too prescriptive about the order of terms. Your code is OK, and will work in theory, using two `LIKE`s. However on a big database it will be slow, and it doesn't have the features of full text search. You can still use it if you wish - if you want to persist with your approach, echo the query that does not work, and try it directly in your database (e.g. MySQL on the console, or phpMyAdmin).

Comment: I've not used full text search in MySQL, but there are loads of examples on the web (including the first chapter link that I gave you).

Comment: i have now added ALTER TABLE store ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (artist, song); with success. is this the right way and what should i do now?

Comment: You can get your MySQL server version from the console and from phpMyAdmin.

Comment: _What should you do now?_ Keep on reading the documentation `:-)`. I mean this kindly: it is not in your long-term learning interest for me to do your research for you. Try the examples from the docs.

Comment: you see the changes ive done?

Comment: Yep. Your question now doesn't make much sense, since it refers to `OR to AND` which no longer exists. Fix that, but also get the SQL you are trying, and run it in your database directly e.g. in the console. Then do some debugging! Create a SQL Fiddle if you want me to see what you are working on.

Comment: now it works but not correctly: for example the complete song named "Artistxxx - Songxxx". If I type "Artistxxx" it founds "Artistxxx". But if I type "artistxxx", it founds nothing. How I define, that the search ignore the uppercase and lowercase?

Comment: Would you fix your question, as per my earlier comment? Your introduction pertains to the previous version of the code, and currently it makes no sense for new readers.  As for the new problem, try searching for "MySQL full text search case insensitive" and see what you come up with. Again, it will do your skills a world of good if you get into the habit of searching prior to asking.

Comment: the question is fixed, thats the new code. the columns artist and song already have the collation utf8_general_ci. the first problem is the case in matches and i cant search part of words, only exact words

Answer (score -1):

You could return results from a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM store
WHERE CONCAT(artist, song) LIKE '%<search>%'
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am an absolute beginner so I can not customize the code like you mean :(

Comment: This will never work. First you are concatenating the artist and song without any kind of delimiter (like a space). Second, you are not taking into account that a user might search with the song first then the artist.

Comment: pstephan1187 can you help me to get on the right way?